# php alternative to strip_tags that allows <, <=, >=, > in sql - regex?

Tags: php, sql, regex, preg-replace, strip-tags

I'm using wp-db.php on a non-Wordpress site which allows a apply_filters function to be used. I initially did this:

```
function apply_filters($type, $input) {
    return strip_tags($input);
}
```

I want to stop html from being saved. I thought I fixed the problem but then noticed that sql queries that included things like <= weren't working.

What I want it to do is to strip tags that begin with a character e.g. `<b...` but if there is a space or equals sign after the bracket e.g. `<` or `<=` then it shouldn't remove it.

I found this code but it doesn't work how I want it to:

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $input);
```

e.g.

```
<b>test</b> abc <= def < ok? ilj >= xyz >
```

gets returned as:

```
test abc = xyz >
```

it should only remove `<x...>` where x is not a space or equals sign and remove `</....>`

BTW I noticed that < script> doesn't work so I think it's ok for < with a space after to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first tag is valid:

```
<b>1</b> <0b>2</0b> < b>3</ > <'b>4</'b> <(>5</(> <=>6</=>
```

This non-greedy regex removes the valid and closing tags:

/`<[^(=\d' )].*?>`/g

in php:

`preg_replace('/<[^(=\d\' )].*?>/', '', $input);`

See https://regex101.com/

I had those other tags due to sql like:

```
col1 < 10
col2 <10
col3 <'2010-10-10'
col4 <(SELECT col5...)
col5 <=20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some preg_match string to perform the operation.  But it's not sure that it will work on all the custom strings.  So you can use the `htmlspecialchars` function  which will change the

```
           &gt; is >

            &lt; is <
```

You can get more about the function here

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

After that apply the `strip_tags` than it will work for you.

So you have to go with preg_match  function.  Try this one.

```
     preg_replace("# <(?![/a-z]) | (?<=\s)>(?![a-z]) #exi", "htmlentities('$0')", $html);
```

Comment: What about sql? It is expecting < and > not &lt; and &gt; Also I want to remove all html such as <b>, <img>, <script> etc. The field is meant for plain text such as their name, etc.

Comment: It didn't remove the bold tag in my example and I'm not sure if it kept the <= as raw text like I want it to